# Error en librería RXTX con Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas tardes me encuentro trabajando con la librería de RXTX para hacer una simulación a un puerto serial con JAVA, pero me esta mandando el siguiente error.
Espero que me puedan apoyar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Codigo JAVA

```
public class puertoController
{
public puertoController()
{
    super();
}

void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: El puerto se encunetra en uso.");
    }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            System.out.println("Se conecto al puerto");
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Solo puertos seriales son aceptados.");
        }
    }     
}

public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{
    InputStream in;

    public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        try
        {
            while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
            {
                System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}

public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
{
    OutputStream out;

    public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {                
            int c = 0;
            while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
            {
                this.out.write(c);
            }                
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}

public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("entra al main");
        (new puertoController()).connect("COM3");
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tienes la posibilidad de utilizar otra libreria que no se la libreria RXTX?

Answer (score 0):

El error dice dos cosas que pueden ser. El jar que bajaste hace referencia interna a una dll lo cual no encuentra. Si la agregaste entonces te falta agregar al java.library.path . Si no tienes idea de donde sacar esa dll busca en la pagina donde bajaste ese jar.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo esta [libreria](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) jSerialComm ya la he utilizado en otras oportunidades y no me ha presentado problema alguno, ahi te dejo links en los que puedes encontrar los recursos a lo que necesites y un pequeño ejemplo de la lectura del puerto COM3:
[Descarga](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fazecast/jSerialComm/1.3.11),
[Pagina](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/),
[Documentación](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/index.html).

```
 SerialPort  comPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("mipuertoCOM3");
    comPort.openPort();
    comPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
        @Override
        public int getListeningEvents() {
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

            if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
                return;
            byte[] newData = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable()];
            int numRead = comPort.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
            String value = new String(newData);
            try {
                System.out.println("Leido: "+value);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```